# How do I get the values from one table based on the relationship specified in another?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database

I have a table called `user_info` which has a *unique* `id` and general information like `title`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `number`, etc..

I have another table `useralias` which has two columns; `userid` and `aliasid`.

At the moment I `select * from user_info where timestamp > 'a timestamp'`.

How can I also append to the results a duplicate of each `user_info` record for each `useralias` record in the alias table based on `userid`, keeping into account the `timestamp`.

Except I want to replace the `userid` with the alias id for these extra records, but return the rest of the details as if there were an exact copy of that `user_info` record except with a different id.

Comment: Can you edit your answer to show what your desired output would look like in tabular format?

Comment: Do SHOW CREATE TABLE user_info and useralias

Comment: Unable to understand your question. Kindly show the required result in tabular format.

Comment: I cant do show create table as it is microsoft sql but the user_info table looks like this

user_id, title, first_name, last_name, email, phone, mobile, photo, timestamp. 1, mr, john, smith, john.smith@gmail.com, 000, 000, server.com/john.png, 20120105091011 2, mrs, jane, smith, jane.smith@gmail.com, 000, 000, server.com/jane.png, 20120105091011

the user_alias table looks like this user_id, alias_id 1, 3

Comment: The output I want would look like this

1, mr, john, smith, john.smith@gmail.com, 000, 000, server.com/john.png, 20120105091011 2, mrs, jane, smith, jane.smith@gmail.com, 000, 000, server.com/jane.png, 20120105091011 3, mr, john, smith, john.smith@gmail.com, 000, 000, server.com/john.png, 20120105091011

Is this possible with a single query??
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the aliases and not the original user id, then a simple join does what you want:

```
select ua.aliasid, <all columns from user that you want>
from user u join
     useralias ua
     on u.userid = ua.userid
```

If you want both the userids and the aliases, then you need to augment the table you are joining to:

```
select ua.aliasid, <all columns from user that you want>
from user u join
     (select userid, aliasid
      from ((select userid, aliasid
             from useralias ua
            )
            union all
            (select userid, userid as aliasid
             from user
            )
           ) t
     ) ua
     on u.userid = ua.userid
```

This query creates a list of pairs of user ids and alias ids and also adds in all existing user ids.  When you join, you'll get the original records.  You could also do this with two separate queries connected by a join.

Comment: Ey Gordon, you're a gun. Solved my problem perfectly. I guess I just have trouble getting my head around using selects in selects and join altogether. Thanks heaps mate.

Comment: The second as I needed both in one result